# Importing pyquery works on IDLE interpreter but not on a script

Tags: python

I am trying to use pyquery in my script, but I am running into a problem when pyquery tries to import etree from lxml. However, this problem does not occur when I import pyquery on the IDLE interpreter itself. So, if I put

```
import pyquery
```

into the IDLE interpreter, it works, no problem. However, if I put

```
import makepath
import pyquery
```

into a script called PyQueryTest.py, it gives in the terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Python 3.5/PythonPrograms/PyQueryTest.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyquery
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyquery/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from .pyquery import PyQuery
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyquery/pyquery.py", line 9, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: cannot import name etree
```

Here, makepath.py is a script which appends the preinstalled Python packages' location to sys.path, and looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/' + \
                '3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
```

I am using a Mac and have installed Python 3.5, so I previously had problems where imports failed in my scripts because my programs all run in a different directory from the preinstalled Python packages. However, in all of my scripts I have run since putting makepath.py in my programs' folder and importing it in my programs, the fix to the path seems to work.

Here, though, there is clearly some issue I can't see. The import works fine in the interpreter, but fails in a script. If someone could point me to a solution, I would be very grateful. Thank you.

--EDIT: For clarification, if I import lxml in the IDLE interpreter, and then call lxml.etree, I get

```
<module 'lxml.etree' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-35m-darwin.so'>
```

So that's where I think etree is located, which is why I'm confused as to why it's not importing correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you have two different Python interpreters installed, and you're getting a different one when you run your script than you get when you start Idle. I don't know enough about Python on MacOS these days to help you sort it out, but perhaps this will point you in the right direction. Perhaps you can explicitly name the Python interpreter you want when you run the script?

Comment: The thing is, I have imported things like praw and used them in scripts without a problem. If there was a problem with different interpreters, wouldn't it show up there? I'll try though, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: It looks like you were exactly correct. I used sys.executable and found that I was running Python2.7 in my scripts, whereas my IDLE uses Python3.5. I simply used a shebang line to specify my script to use Python3.5, and it worked like a charm! Thank you very much, sir.